# Error when shutting down asyncio server in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, terminate

I am rather new to asyncio programming with python, and I am encoutering an error which I am unable to resolve even after extensive googling. In short, I have a server implementation (python 3.7) which is running **two** asyncio-based server components, one MQTT listener, and one raw TCP listener. When terminating the server via `CTRL+C`, I will get errors about pending tasks which have been destroyed before completion.

Since the server code is a bit large already, I was able to create this small example, which is using the same API calls and is causing the same issue:

```
import asyncio

async def start():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(on_connected, '127.0.0.1', 51000)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

async def on_connected(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()

server_task = None
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    server_task = loop.create_task(start())
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    pass
finally:
    server_task.cancel()
    asyncio.ensure_future(server_task)
    loop.close()
```

When running and terminating via `CTRL-C` I will get:

```
$ python3 serv
^CTask was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<start() running at serv:243> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
```

According to the docs and the [the asyncio.Task description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) I would expect the following to happen:

- upon `CTRL-C` the execution of the event loop is interrupted and the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is raised, which I am ignoring above
- the `finally` block is executed (event loop still stopped)
- `server_task.cancel()` will mark the task for cancellation (yet not doing anything yet)
- `asyncio.ensure_future(server_task)` will actually wait for the task to be canceled
- `loop.close` should close the default event loop (which - to my knowledge - should have been started again by `asyncio.ensure_future(server_task)`)

Now I can google several similar examples, where people iterate all pending tasks and stop them, however I am a bit careful here since the issue is really only with the *TCP listener*, and the *MQTT listener* successfully terminates itself and I don't want to interfere with that.

Obviously, I still have some misunderstanding here, so some async-expert please come to the rescue! :)

Comment: `asyncio.ensure_future(server_task)` is no-op because the server_task is already a future. That function knows how to convert an arbitrary awaitable to something that inherits from `Future`, it doesn't actually _run_ anything. Instead, you probably need something like `try: loop.run_until_complete(server_task) except CancelledError: pass` to spin up the event loop to process the cancellation.

Comment: Ok so this is going to throw a `CancelledError`, which is *okay*, since depending on the scheduler the task may actually be cancelled already? So this is how one would do it?

Comment: Okay in the small example it seems to work, while in my implementation with the 2 listeners it will throw a `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`. So I can neither `await`, because I am outside of any function, nor can I `run_until_complete`, so what can I do? :/

Comment: That seems like material for a separate question, because it seems like a different issue, on different code. There is also a possibility that asyncio is just not designed for this kind of clean recovery from ^C.